# how to limit user to insert data to MySQL just 1 time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to build a blog witch has like and dislike button. My problem is when user click on like button I can't actually limit him to not do that again and not like the post again and again and again. I use ajax(`$.post`) with JQuery to insert data.

**How can i do that? Do i need to change my database structure?**

```
var did_liked = 0;
$("#insert_like").click(function (e) {
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
    did_liked +=1 ;
    if (did_liked == 1) {
        $.post("./inc/like.php", {
            post_id_like: post_id
        }, function (data, status) {
            $("#insert_like").text(data);
        });
    }
});
$("#insert_dislike").click(function (e) {
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
    $.post("./inc/like.php", {
        post_id_dislike: post_id
    }, function (data, status) {
        $("#insert_dislike").text(data);
    });
});
```

With `did_liked` I can prevent user to don't like it again but if he refresh the page he can do so.

My db:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEppZ.jpg)

Comment: 1/ Add unique id on your database so you can only have one "like" entry by user / article OR 2/ In your php add a select before the insert and if you already have a like / displike for this user / post send back an error

Comment: you also need to capture the IP address and assign to the selected value

Comment: @mickael every post on my db has post_like and post_dislike column, and also every post has primary key (post_id). you say i need to create a table called like or so?

Comment: @emre yes that was good but how can i assign it and where?

Comment: what is the content of like.php? You need to edit that file and create a table in your database for the ip addresses.

Comment: @Technotures I assume you have one table for `USER` + one table for `ARTICLE`? I don't get the point of the "post_like" / "post_dislike" column, but you should make a new table `LIKE_DISLIKE` (or whatever you want) that look like `id | id_user | id_article | like` with `like = 0 or 1` and an unique id on `id_user + id_article`. That way you can't add an other like / dislike for the same user on the same article ! And add some `$('button').attr('disabled', true)` when user click so he can't do it again the time you add the like !

Comment: _Side note:_ If you store the IP and the users are within EU, remember to adhere to GDPR since IP-addresses are counted as a personal and identifiable property.

Comment: @Technotures what is the purpose of the column `post_like` and `post_dislike`? It's the sum of all the like and dislike on this article? If yes, you just need to update the field after each like / dislike, but with a `like` table it's a waste since you can have the information by make a simple select and count the row for this article (with my example : `select count(*) from like where id_article = :id_article and like = 1` for the like and ... `... and like = 0` for the dislike)

Comment: And question because @eMRe got a point : every one can like / displike or only connected user?

Comment: @Mickael Leger that's true i create like and dislike coulmn to sum all the like and dislike for the article. i guess i think i've shouldn't create more tables idk. is creating more tables (more than 10) effects on you website performance and speed?

Comment: @Mickael Leger i've been coding with php about two months and i'm still dis coveting it. most of the website won't allow users to like/dislike articles if they weren't login in their website.

Comment: i just start to design it and i think user should log in to like/dislike articles.

Comment: @Technotures If YOU are coding, it's up to you to allow user no connected to like / dislike an article, it's just harder to be sure that a person don't like / dislike multiple time if you can't identify him :) And about the database structure, you will learn by doing stuff, a lot of table is good to be more flexible. If you have very few BIG table and you need to make ONE change, it's possible that it will impact a lot of think...but with flexible table you can change structure easily. And no need to add field if you can get the information in other table !

Comment: @Mickael Leger Sure. thanks for your time and sharing information! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some idea to avoid user to add multiple like / dislike by article :

**1/ Create a `like` table with unique id** :

```
TABLE LIKE
=====================================
id_like | id_user | id_article | like
```

With an unique id on `id_user and id_article` so the same user can't like / dislike the same article twice and `like = 1 or 0`

**2/ Check if you already have one like before insert**

In your php, before doing the insert :

```
select /* your request to check if you have a like for this user in this article */;
```

Then check if you got something :

```
if (count ( /* what you fetch */) === 0) {
    /* you insert because you have no data */
} else {
    /* you don't insert */
}
```

Btw, you should add

```
$("#insert_like").attr('disabled', true);
$("#insert_dislike").attr('disabled', true);
```

when user click so he can't multiple click, and remove the `disabled` when your Ajax call is complete.

Comment: what if you are not a user but want to like/dislike the post?

Comment: many sites wont allow you to like or dislike their articles if you weren't sign in!

Comment: @eMRe good point, I will ask OP ! But how can you avoid one user that is not connected to like / dislike an article from multiple computer? If the user is not connected, I see no solution to avoid him to click like from home, dislike from work, like again from a friend house, etc. do you have an idea?

Comment: You can`t really stop that happening completely. If you capture their IP then you make it harder to vote multiple times. Again, they can disconnect the router and connect again to get a new IP if it is dynamically assigned. The best way is to allow only the registered users to vote.

Answer (score 1):

Make a table with userID, LikedPostID, DislikedPostID column.
After you can check this:

```
SELECT LikedPostID, DislikedPostID FROM tblUserLikes WHERE userID='$user'
```

in PHP

```
if ($LikedPostID == $thisPostID || $DislikedPostID == $thisPostID) { // make a like or dislike button to disable state }
```